# SQL rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a table which represents a list

```
id  |  item_type  |  item_id
----------------------------
1      'article'     24
2      'post'        9
3      'article'     120
4      'image'       9
```

item_type basically represent from which table the row is suppose to be and id is the id from that table. Which means that for example second and fourth line are not the same.

I would like to get lets say item_title and more columns which are going to be created differently based on each table. 
Lets say if item_type = 'article', then item_title = title from that table.
 But if item_type is 'image' item_title = author_first_name + author_second_name + image_id 
etc...

I was googling it or how to approach it. Particularly I thought I could be solved by sql if statement with subqueries but so far was unable to make a real progress. So I would like to ask for help or point out the right direction.

Comment: could you pleas give us more information? Are you going to add these fields:item_title,author_first_name , author_second_name , image_id to current table or making view?

Comment: The answer bellow is what I was looking for but now I'm having difficulties to add more then one column without repeating the whole case when syntax. 

Now I'm trying to aciave something like 
when i.item_type = 'article' then a.title, a.anotherColumn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform `OUTER JOIN`s to all those tables and compose a title using the appropriate columns, as in:

```
select
    i.*,
    case 
      when i.item_type = 'article' then a.title
      when i.item_type = 'post'    then p.post_title
      when i.item_type = 'image'   then
        g.author_first_name + g.author_second_name + g.image_id
    end as item_title
  from item i
  left join article a on i.item_id = a.id
  left join post    p on i.item_id = p.id
  left join image   g on i.item_id = g.id
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Comment: Actually how I can create more columns like this ?

when i.item_type = 'article' then a.title, a.source?

Comment: Copy the whole CASE section, from `case` until `end as item_title`.

Comment: Yeah I figure that but isnt there a better solution? The sql statemnt would get ridiculusly long with just several columns

Comment: Using the OP's example, if the article table contains id's 9, 24 and 120 then you'll have joined it on to all four input rows, even though it's only needed for one of them...  Would that not make it sensible to have `left join article a on i.item_id = a.id AND i.item_type = 'article'`?

Answer (score 3):

Although the accepted answer is accurate and relatively concise, it is also laborious.  *(The `article` table is being joined to `post` and `image` rows, even though the results are then discarded.)*

To improve that you could start with...

```
select
    i.*,
    case 
      when i.item_type = 'article' then a.title
      when i.item_type = 'post'    then p.post_title
      when i.item_type = 'image'   then g.author_first_name + g.author_second_name + g.image_id
    end as item_title
  from item i
  left join article a on i.item_id = a.id AND i.item_type = 'article'
  left join post    p on i.item_id = p.id AND i.item_type = 'post'
  left join image   g on i.item_id = g.id AND i.item_type = 'image'
```

Many optimisers don't actually like that though.  If you really want to get the most out of your database, I would put an index on `item(item_type)` and then use explicit logic for each type...

```
   SELECT i.*, a.title
     FROM item i
LEFT JOIN article a ON i.item_id = a.id
    WHERE i.item_type = 'acticle'

UNION ALL

   SELECT i.*, p.post_title
     FROM item i
LEFT JOIN post p ON i.item_id = p.id
    WHERE i.item_type = 'post'

UNION ALL

   SELECT i.*, g.author_first_name + g.author_second_name + g.image_id
     FROM item i
LEFT JOIN image g ON i.item_id = g.id
    WHERE i.item_type = 'image'
```

More long winded, but much more explicit and optimiser friendly.

Comment: Good alternative. Upvoting.

Comment: I'm also creating more than the column title. Would you know how to improve it so when I have "end as item_title" and need another like item_author I dont have to copy the whole case statement?

Comment: @MarekBarta - There are lots of alternatives, but they depend on which dialect of SQL you're using.  MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, BigQuery, etc, etc.  I recommend editing your question with a more complete example *(both the data coming in and the data going out)* and specifying which DBMS you're using.

Comment: @MarekBarta - Hello?